# Get the position of clicked word in textbox (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox with multiple sentences, and when I click on a word, I need to get the position of the word in this textbox.

The code actually just get the whole text from the textarea and writes it in another text area. I am struggling to get specific position of the character (or word) I clicked on.

What it should do is to copy just the text before clicked word/character.

```js
 var themaintextarea = document.getElementById('textarea'); 
 themaintextarea.addEventListener('click', replace_sentence);
 function replace_sentence(e){
  var themaintext = document.getElementById("textarea").innerHTML;
    //alert(thereplace);
    document.getElementById("curent_sentence").value = themaintext;
    theselection = window.getSelection();
    var therange = theselection.getRangeAt(0);
    var sometext = therange.toString().trim();
    alert(sometext);
    
 }
```

```html
<textarea id="curent_sentence"></textarea>

<div id="textarea" contenteditable>I <span>like</span> apples. I <span>like</span> apples. 
<br>
I <span>like</span> apples.</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED : Heres the fiddle to select the word before the word clicked on. Note: no spans are used in this. https://jsfiddle.net/Lnkav5ca/5/

I think i understood what you're looking for. https://jsfiddle.net/Lnkav5ca/1/ I put all the clickable words in a class and add event listeners to that class. So when the word is clicked on it gets inserted into the text box.

```
var themaintextarea = document.getElementsByClassName('clickable'); 
for (var i = 0; i < themaintextarea.length; i++) {   
themaintextarea[i].addEventListener('click', replace_sentence);
}
function replace_sentence(e){
console.log(e);
    var themaintext = e.target.innerHTML
//alert(thereplace);
document.getElementById("curent_sentence").value = themaintext;
theselection = window.getSelection();
var therange = theselection.getRangeAt(0);
var sometext = therange.toString().trim();
//alert(sometext);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I wanted to do all this without adding any span, but I guess that is not possible?

Comment: Anyways is it possible to get previous element ... like the word before. I realise the solution is to put 2 words in one span I would get both of them but is it possible to do it other ways.

Comment: hey i have a way to do it without a span. hold on. im making a fiddle for it

Comment: Awesome ... will try it meantime with span.

Comment: So you want to get the word clicked on or the previous word?

Comment: If there is possibility to know previous word, I would like to get them both.

Comment: I have problems when I have others spans inside the main span - for example when I have something like this it doesn't select the whole thing - <span class="clickable"><span class="else">I</span> like <span class="else">apples</span> </span>

Comment: please check my updated answer. ive included a third fiddle to click on the previous word. this solution does not involve using spans

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139651/discussion-between-lhavcoder-and-brana).

Comment: Hi, actually I was able to solve the problem using parrent node so everything is good.